# Joda DateTime with TimeZone Information

Tags: datetime, timezone, jodatime

I have the following:

```scala
val startWithTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC)
val endWithTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC)
val intervalWithTZ = new Interval(startWithTZ, endWithTZ)

val startWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00")
val endWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00")
val intervalWithoutTZ = new Interval(startWithoutTZ, endWithoutTZ)
```

With this, I now do the following:

```scala
val utcInterval = new Interval(intervalWithoutTZ.getStart.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC),
intervalWithoutTZ.getEnd.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

What I see with the utcInterval is not what I was expecting:

```
2016-09-30T22:00:00.000Z/2016-10-01T09:00:00.000Z
```

Why is this? I was expecting the utcInterval to be:

```
2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z/2016-10-01T11:00:00.000Z
```

Here is what I get when I use the Scala REPL:

```scala
scala> import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time._

scala> val startWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00")
startWithoutTZ: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00

scala> val endWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00")
endWithoutTZ: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2016-10-01T11:00:00.000+02:00

scala> val intervalWithoutTZ = new Interval(startWithoutTZ, endWithoutTZ)
intervalWithoutTZ: org.joda.time.Interval = 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00/2016-10-01T11:00:00.000+02:00

scala> val utcInterval = new Interval(intervalWithoutTZ.getStart.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC),
     | intervalWithoutTZ.getEnd.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC))
utcInterval: org.joda.time.Interval = 2016-09-30T22:00:00.000Z/2016-10-01T09:00:00.000Z

scala>
```

Why is it not?

Comment: What is your local timezome? UTC-2?

Comment: Given that this is really about Joda Time rather than Scala, it would probably be better to give an example in Java, given that that's more widely used.

Comment: It makes no big difference. It is just the same way of instantiating the Interval and DateTime objects!

Comment: Yes, but it makes it easier for people to help you if they can copy and paste your code into a familiar environment. (It would be even better if this were a short but complete example...)

Comment: The result you've given is actually very strange, and I suspect it's due to typos - your start seems to be 2 hours later than expected, but the end seems to be 2 hours *earlier*. Are you sure that's *really* the result you got?

Comment: Yes, I'm just printing it out from the console!

Comment: Well, currently you're not printing out anything. If you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and specify your time zone, we should be able to reproduce it. I suspect we'll actually see one with an end point of 2016-10-01T13:00:00Z or a start point of 2016-09-30T22:00:00Z though.

Comment: You are right! I have edited my post!

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't edit the first part of the post... I've done that now. Please take more care in future - and as I say, if you're asking a question about an API which will primarily be used in Java, and the Scala interaction is irrelevant, writing a short but complete program in Java is likely to make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, I've always felt that an `Interval` should be between two `Instant` values rather than two `DateTime` values. However, the Joda Time API is what it is.

When you create an `Interval` from two `DateTime` values, the end time is converted into the time zone of the start time. In your case, this doesn't actually need to do anything because for `intervalWithTZ` they're both in UTC, and for `intervalWithoutTZ` they're both in your system default time zone. Your naming is inaccurate here, because all the values *are* in a time zone, even though you didn't specify one. A `DateTime` always has a time zone; for a value without a time zone you want `LocalDateTime` instead.

So, we can get rid of your `intervalWithoutTZ` and simply write your code as:

```
DateTime startInDefaultZone = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00")
DateTime endInDefaultZone = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00")

val utcInterval = new Interval(startInDefaultZone.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC),
                               endInDefaultZone.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));
```

That won't change the result at all... but the basic point is that you're converting a `DateTime` of "2016-10-01T00:00:00 in your system default time zone" into UTC... and presumably your default time zone is 2 hours behind UTC, so 11am in UTC is 9am in your local time, etc.

In short, we can actually get rid of intervals entirely here - what you're seeing can be shown more simply as:

```
DateTime startInDefaultZone = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00")
DateTime startInUtc = startInDefaultZone.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

You appear to expect that to be 2016-10-01T00:00:00Z, but it's actually "the instant in time represented by `startInDefaultZone`, but expressed in UTC" which is 2016-10-01T02:00:00Z on your machine.

If you *really* want to "change time zone without changing local values" you could use `withZoneRetainFields`, e.g.

```
DateTime startInDefaultZone = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00")
DateTime startInUtc = startInDefaultZone.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

However, that usually means you've used the wrong type to start with, and should have been using `LocalDateTime`. It's rarely a useful operation in a well-designed system.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your local timezone is UTC-2 at the moment, and since you give no Timezone info to the "withoutTZ" variables, Joda-Time give it the default (local) timezone.

In order to change the timezone *[à posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori)*, you have to convert your `DateTime` to a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object, and then convert it back to `DateTime` with the correct timezone, here's an example reusing your code in Java.

**EDIT2:**
As suggested by @JonSkeet, it's better to directly use  `DateTime.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone)` on your `DateTime` object instead of converting it.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.Interval;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime startWithTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC);
        DateTime endWithTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC);
        Interval intervalWithTZ = new Interval(startWithTZ, endWithTZ);

        DateTime startWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T00:00:00");
        DateTime endWithoutTZ = new DateTime("2016-10-01T11:00:00");
        Interval intervalWithoutTZ = new Interval(startWithoutTZ, endWithoutTZ);

        Interval utcInterval =
            new Interval(intervalWithoutTZ.getStart().withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC),
                         intervalWithoutTZ.getEnd().withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC));

        System.out.println(utcInterval);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z/2016-10-01T11:00:00.000Z

**EDIT:**

As @JonSkeet mentionned in his comment, you are getting weird results, consult his comment to correct your output.

Comment: You don't have to convert to `LocalDateTime` and back - at least not in your code - `DateTime.withZoneRetainFields` will do it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip, i forgot about that, i'll edit my code.